# DTD Remote Reference Problem

Tags: xml, dtd, docbook

I have a customized dtd that contains a reference to a remote dtd like:

```
<!ENTITY % table.model     PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Exchange Table Model 19990315//EN" "http://www.docbook.org/sgml/4.2/soextblx.dtd">
```

However, docbook site was down for at least 1 day in mid March 2011, our content won't validate. So I was thinking making a local copy of the soextblx.dtd and change reference to that may help, like:

```
  <!ENTITY % table.model     PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Exchange Table Model 19990315//EN" "soextblx.dtd">
```

Assuming that I have put "soextblx.dtd" in the same folder as my customized dtd. I have used XmlSpy to validate it, which is validated, but I am not sure whether this is the correct or best solution for this kind of server-down problem that may happen in the future.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Looks right to me, but I'd like to hear from an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Interesting approach @ mzjn -- seems like XML catalog is an abstraction of the public/system concept.*

Back to your original question -- you **are** doing it the right way according to the [DTD ref regarding the External Entity declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-ExternalID).

Relevant excerpt:

> A URI might thus be **relative to the
>   document entity**, to the entity
>   containing the external DTD subset, or
>   to some other external parameter
>   entity. Attempts to retrieve the
>   resource identified by a URI may be
>   redirected at the parser level (for
>   example, in an entity resolver) or
>   below (at the protocol level, for
>   example, via an HTTP Location:
>   header). In the absence of additional
>   information outside the scope of this
>   specification within the resource, **the
>   base URI of a resource is always the
>   URI of the actual resource returned**.
>   In other words, it is the URI of the
>   resource retrieved after all
>   redirection has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The best general solution to this kind of problem is to use an [XML catalog](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html). In short, a catalog provides a mapping from generic identifiers to specific (local) files or URIs.

Here are two good articles about catalogs (especially useful for DocBook users):

- http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Catalogs.html.
- http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html